# Material-UI TreeView TreeItems background

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I don't know if it's bug or feature, when I used these dependacies:

```
"@material-ui/core": "4.8.3",
"@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.37"
```

After losing focus from some TreeItem and selecting another TreeItem, I didnt see any TreeItem backgroud on TreeItems selected previously.

[image: before]

Now, after updating to:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3"
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57"
```

I can see some light blue background on TreeItems, that were selected to node expending.
[image]
So maybe it's some new feature, and someone know how to disable it?

Comment: Can you share a sandbox link?

Comment: This is not my solution, but still the same problem. https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-5kfbl?file=/package.json:288-397

Comment: Try to change dependencies to: "@material-ui/core": "4.8.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "4.5.1",
    "@material-ui/lab": "4.0.0-alpha.37" to see the difference

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Overriding current styles of `TreeItem` like below will remove the unwanted background color. [SandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xh8pi?file=/demo.js)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  "@global": {
    ".MuiTreeItem-root.Mui-selected > .MuiTreeItem-content .MuiTreeItem-label": {
      backgroundColor: "white"
    },
    ".MuiTreeItem-root.Mui-selected > .MuiTreeItem-content .MuiTreeItem-label:hover, .MuiTreeItem-root.Mui-selected:focus > .MuiTreeItem-content .MuiTreeItem-label": {
      backgroundColor: "gray"
    }
  }
});
```